# How do items stack in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I've been playing around with [Terrasavr](http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/) for building things in Terraria and was wondering what are the stacking categories, for example fallen stars stack up to 99 and dirt stacks up to 999. Is there a certain category that stacks a certain way? What items stack at 99 and what items stack at 999?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the [Terraria Wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki) at the pages for individual items, you can see how many items can be in a stack for each item.

For example, [buckets](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Buckets) stack to 99, whereas most [potions](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Potions) stack to 30. It really just depends on the item.

Usually, any tiles or building materials will stack to 999, whilst crafting materials will only stack to 99. Also, most tools and weapons will only stack to 1, with a few exceptions such as the [Light Disc](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Light_Disc) which stacks to 5 instead.

Comment: this got duplicated with a question that was in the 1.2 update, as this is in 1.3.